# Python Console UI Suggestions

Tags: python, console-application, curses, urwid

I'm currently rewriting a perl console application that was using curses, and planning to implement it in Python. So far I've narrowed my library options to straight curses, urwid, and dialog.

The application is basically an installer for an appliance that will accommodate basic configuration (network options, hostname, etc). Are there any suggestions or advocates for one of these over the other? Any serious limitations with urwid or dialog?

Comment: Well, `curses` is in the stdlib - a pretty strong plus if you ask me.

Answer (score 4):

urwid is a very complete UI interface and you can do almost everything. In fact, I'm developing an app using urwid. But, as Paulo Scardine said, dialog is a better choice for a wizard-like app.

Answer (score 2):

Dialog is very easy to use and a good choice for an installer using 'wizard-like' interface.